# Find schools that have more than 1 order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out all the schools that have more than 1 order for the same school. In the below example, I want to find school no 2

```
| school_ucn    | order_no  |
-----------------------------
| 1             | 101       | 
| 1             | 101       | 
| 2             | 102       | 
| 2             | 102       | 
| 2             | 103       | 
| 2             | 103       |
```

Should the query be like this:

```
select 
    school_ucn, count(otc_order_number)
from storiacloud.schl_storia_revenue_fact
group by
    otc_order_number, school_ucn
having count(otc_order_number) > 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the order number from your groupby

```
select 
     school_ucn,count(DISTINCT otc_order_number) 
from 
   storiacloud.schl_storia_revenue_fact
group by 
    school_ucn 
having 
    count(distinct otc_order_number)>1
```

Comment: I would use `COUNT(DISTINCT otc_order_number)`, based on OP's desired output.

Comment: modified the answer as correctly suggested by @FelixPamittan. Tx